# ActionScript and weak reference behavior

Tags: actionscript, behavior, weak-references

I read some articles about ActionScript's weak references. There are two types.

1. Trick with `Dictionary` class.
2. `EventDispatcher` class.

I expected weakly referenced object to be disappeared **immediately** when last strong reference removed. (regardless of GC behavior) But those tricks didn't work like that. The object referenced only weakly still live a while, and looks disappear when next GC time. Removing all of strong references didn't make weakly referenced object to be disappeared from object graph. (I know it'll not be deleted immediately)

Am I wrong or just ActionScript is using different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all weak references mean is that the GC doesn't count it as a reference to an object - reference counting is one of the ways that the GC knows an object is still in use. You still need the garbage collection to run before the memory is reclaimed.

If you want an overview of how Garbage collection works, check out that: http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3 (my own site) or that: http://jpauclair.net/2009/12/23/tamarin-part-iii-current-garbage-collector-in-flash-10-0/ (goes really in depth)